# How to call an action on a route using closure actions?

Tags: ember.js

I've got `openModal` action defined on application route. I'm trying to call this action from within a component.

If I use syntax for action bubbling:

`{{my-component openModal="openModal"}}`

then everything works as expected and I can trigger this action using `this.sendAction("openModal")`.

However, I'm not sure how to get the same result using the new closure syntax:

`{{my-component openModal=(action "openModal")}}`

In this case, Ember complains that there's no action `openModal` defined on the controller. Do I have to define this action on every controller that uses `my-component`? Is there a way to somehow use `target` option to tell Ember that this action is defined on a route? Is it ok to mix bubbling and closure syntax in a single component?

I'm using Ember 2.0 beta 1.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Until routable components are introduced somewhere in Ember <s>2.1 or 2.2 or 2.3 or 2.4 or 2.5 or 2.6</s> or 2.7, it is impossible to pass a closure action from a route.

For now, you can only pass closure actions from a controller and on to child components.

**UPD:** Miko Paderes hints that an addon is available: https://github.com/dockyard/ember-route-action-helper

Comment: I upvote cause you answered the question, I wish I could downvote the technical reality though. Actions only on controllers seems crazy to me

Comment: It's just a halfway state we're in until routeable component land and controllers stop being used for routes like this.

Comment: For now, while routable components aren't available, you can use this [addon](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-route-action-helper).

Comment: [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) is basically deprecated now. The read me states: "WARNING:
You probably don't need to use this addon. Most of the use cases you'd use this addon for are perfectly achievable without this addon."

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
{{my-component openModal=(action send "openModal")}}
```

...which makes use of the [send](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_send) method on the controller.

I can't say I fully understand it given that the second argument to `send` is the `context` but it is still passing additional arguments to my action in the route correctly. I'm currently using version *2.4.5*.

Comment: Within the ember documentation, `context` is frequently used to mean 'other arguments'. An excerpt from the page you linked to "Any parameters supplied after the actionName string will be passed as arguments to the action target function."

Answer (score 8):

You can send closure actions to the route by proxying them through the controller.  This works with any Ember version that supports closure actions.  The only caveat is that the action name must differ from controller and route.

For instance, given this template:

```
{{foo-component myAction=(action 'foo')}}
```

You would need a `foo` action on your controller, which could proxy to the route:

```
proxyFooTo: 'fooBar',
actions: {

  foo(context) {
    this.send('proxyFooTo', context);
  }

}
```

Then on the route

```
actions: {
  fooBar(context) {  ... handle fooBar ... } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to avoid creating a controller, or if there is one already avoid adding more logic in it, by specifying the target property

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fiwokenoyu/1/edit?html,js,output

in route

**js**

```
setupController(controller,model){
  this._super(...arguments);
  controller.set('theRoute', this);
},
actions:{
  openModal(data){
    /*...*/
  }
}
```

in template

**hbs**

```
{{my-component openModalAction=(action 'openModal' target=theRoute)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Ember add-on called ember-route-action-helper,

https://github.com/dockyard/ember-route-action-helper

You can just replace `route-action` with `action` at the time "routable- components" become available.

```
{{todo-list todos=model addTodo=(route-action "addTodo")}}
```

So the code above has a similar effect as

Inside the route,

```
setupController(controller,model){
  this._super(...arguments);
  controller.set('theRoute', this);
},
actions:{
  addTodo(data){
    /*...*/
  }
}
```

Inside the HBS,

```
{{todo-list addTodo=(action 'addTodo' target=theRoute)}}
```