# Template/handlesbars cannot find action

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Ember version 2.2

So I have these two routes defined
/Build
/Build/education

Inside of the education route I have a component, and I'm trying to pass an action to it.

Education.hbs

```
  {{#each model as |school|}}
        {{common-education-institution model=school  onAddSubject=(action 'addSubject')}}
    {{/each}}
```

And I have an action defined in education.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
model() {
    return this.modelFor('build').get('education');
}, 
actions: {
    addSubject() {

    }
}
});
```

When I start the app I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: An action named 'addSubject' was not found in (generated build.education controller).
```

Education is a route not a controller, why is this error coming up??

Also I would like to define the action in build.js rather than education.js but the above is a greater problem. 
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Closure actions communicate with the controller and not the route.

Comment: is there a way to make it work with a route? I've been trying to get the app working with routes and components

Comment: Yes you ll have to use regular actions and send them from the component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closure actions should be defined on controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866969/closure-actions-should-be-defined-on-controller)

Comment: Check this answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101296/how-to-call-an-action-on-a-route-using-closure-actions